# Visual Studio 2015 required packages are missing

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I have an issue when run Dependency Checker (Tools-Options-Tools for Apache Cordova) in VS, which is One or more required packages are missing regarding "Android Package: extra-android-support"... But I can't find the required file in Android SDK Manager as shown in this image [from Android SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgLQe.png).

I have read almost all questions related to the same issue but without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

> One or more required packages are missing regarding "Android Package: extra-android-support"... But I can't find the required file in Android SDK Manager

Open the Android SDK Manager of your Tools for Apache Cordova, You can check/override the path of it under `Tools->Options->Tools For Apache Cordova->Environment Variable Overrides->ADT_HOME`.

Then select `Android Support Repository` under Extra folder and install it:

[image]

Comment: I already have the Android Support Repository installed but still I am getting the same issue.

Comment: Could you please try it on an empty blank project? If the error persists, please post the whole error log.

Comment: Again, I got the same error with an empty blank project.... from where I can get the error log to post it here?